# Trouble with SQLite Query/Subquery

Tags: sqlite, group-by, android-sqlite, average, conditional-aggregation

I am having trouble with a SQLite query and I've tried googling it over the last few days, but I don't even know what the operation is called to come up with relevant answers.

I have a pretty standard SQLite table with 10 columns, but only 3 are important here - MS (milliseconds), Version, Buildings

What I am trying todo is create a table that looks like this -

| Buildings | Version1 | Version2 | Version3 | Version4 | Version5 | etc... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | avg(MS) | avg(MS) | avg(MS) | avg(MS) | avg(MS) | avg(MS) |
| 2 | avg(MS) | avg(MS) | avg(MS) | avg(MS) | avg(MS) | avg(MS) |
| 3 | avg(MS) | avg(MS) | avg(MS) | avg(MS) | avg(MS) | avg(MS) |

The tricky part is that there are an unknown number of versions and even the version names themselves are unknown. What I have been using is something like this -

`SELECT avg(ms), version, buildings From loadtimes group by buildings, version`

which creates a table like this -

| avg(ms) | version | buildings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 39527 | 22.5.1-0.4 | 1 |
| 31150 | 22.5.2-1.1 | 1 |
| 65833 | 22.5.1-0.4 | 2 |
| 76612 | 22.5.2-1.1 | 2 |
| 59430 | 22.5.1-0.4 | 3 |
| 105924 | 22.5.2-1.1 | 3 |

Which does give me the information I need, just not in the format where I can graph it.

What is this type of operation called? and how do I create a table with multiple unknown columns?

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: SQLite does not support that kind of dynamic pivoting.

Comment: well that would be a decent reason why I couldn't find anything online about it

Comment: @forpas - would it be possible to hardcode the versions in? so the columns/query would be - `SELECT buildings, version1 where version = "22.5.2-1.1", version2 where version = '22.5.1-0.4'`

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can hardcode the versions, then use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT buildings,
       AVG(CASE WHEN version = '22.5.1-0.4' THEN ms END) AS "Version 22.5.1-0.4",
       AVG(CASE WHEN version = '22.5.2-1.1' THEN ms END) AS "Version 22.5.2-1.1"
       ........................................................
FROM loadtimes
GROUP BY buildings;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1f43b2dc3c93d755f87abadacac176c0).